# Can a Dragonborn Sorcerer have their Dragonbreath spell in addition to another encounter spell?

Tags: spells, dnd-4e, sorcerer, dragonborn

At first level, you would usually have only one encounter spell. Can you, as a sorcerer, have your "Dragonbreath" spell in addition to another encounter spell?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 11):

### Racial powers are in addition to class powers

*Dragon Breath* is a racial power granted to Dragonborn. The relevant rule for Racial Traits appears on page 32 of the fourth edition *Player’s Handbook* (emphasis mine):

> **Racial Power:** Several races give you access to a racial power, which is *an extra power you gain at 1st level in addition to the powers your class gives you*.

So you get this power as well as the usual 1st level allotment of two at-will powers, an encounter power, and a daily power (plus any additional class feature powers, if a class has them; sorcerers do not).

(Later rules added an alternative racial power for Dragonborn, which you could take instead of *Dragon Breath*. But it works the same in terms of how many powers you choose.)